# Druid animal companions

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid

I currently have a Druid in my game that is approaching epic level. In the epic level handbook there is a passage that I cannot find clarification on. The passage reads:

> **Animal Companion:** The druid may have a maximum number of animal companions equal to twice her class level, as normal.

This implies to me that a druid may have multiple animal companions. I have searched the player handbook, epic level handbook, and the complete adventurer for an answer to this question. Is this question answered in another book that I do not own?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting a [relevant topic from community.wizards.com](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19530462/Epic_Animal_Companion):

from the [DMG Errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/DMG_Errata032004.zip):

(*Careful, the link points to a zip file from Wizards.com. Always scan files for viruses etc upon download!*)

> **Epic Druid**
>
> Dungeon Master’s Guide, page 208
>
> *Problem:* Druids no longer get multiple animal companions.
>
> *Solution:* Replace the Animal Companion paragraph with the following
>   text:
>
> *Animal Companion:* The epic druid’s animal companion continues to
>   increase in power. At every three levels higher than 18th (21st, 24th,
>   27th, and so on), the companion gains
>   +2 bonus Hit Dice, its natural armor increases by 2, its Strength and Dexterity modifiers increase by 1, and it learns one additional bonus
>   trick.